# Using konva js can I create a floor plan

Tags: angular, konvajs

I want to create a floor plan using a software we have created. We created a program which can draw the seats and area on floor. I want to able to draw the floor on it can I use `konva` for that?

I tried using the my custom algorithm in javascript but it can't draw customized thing.

Comment: If you don't know the capabilities of the program you created then how can we answer?

Comment: Your question is too broad. What did you try already? What went wrong? What did you expect to happen? Edit your question and add more detail.

Comment: We’re happy to help you, but in order to improve your chances of getting an answer, read up on these guidelines stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask